# AngularJs Select ng-option set object selected

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an object inside a select ng-options, but i need to select the second one, how can i do that?

here is a example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NTdaDNFFbbDlu7fJOeDK

```
$scope.prop = [
    {t: "Service 1", j:"oi1"},
    {t: "Service 2", j:"oi2"},
    {t: "Service 3", j:"oi3"},
] ;

$scope.prop.value.j = "oi2";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `ng-model` attribute should be different from select options array, in this case, let's rename it  to `selected_value`. Then, in your controller, you can assign it with the second option from `$scope.prop`

```
$scope.prop = [
    {t: "Service 1", j:"oi1"},
    {t: "Service 2", j:"oi2"},
    {t: "Service 3", j:"oi3"},
] ;


$scope.selected_value = $scope.prop[2]
```

Then in your select html.

```
  <select ng-model="prop.selected_value" ng-options="v.j for v in prop">
  </select>
```

Comment: How can I use using a string like: "oi2"

$scope.selected_value,j = "oi2"

Comment: `$scope.selected_value.j = "oi2"`,  you can do that.

Comment: @PedroMarques you first need to assign `selected_value` and then trying to modify  his `'j'` value.  Check it http://plnkr.co/edit/mKJTEDRphSIlOrYoxcIH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set your `value.j` to an empty String in your controller, because you don't need to do this in controller.

```
$scope.prop.value.j = "";
```

Then, in the following code, add `ng-init`: (the code comes from your posted Plunker link, and I just added the ng-init directive to select the `index of 1` (2nd entry in the array)

```
<select ng-init="prop.value = prop.value || prop[1]" ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v.j for v in prop">
```

Comment: this is not elegant solution. why use ng-init, just initialize within controller.

Comment: Assuming the OP just knows the index he/she wants to select, without having to know the content of the selection, because the data may come from a dynamic service layer that has different content for the second element in the data array.

Comment: you can do it from controller.